# $b^x\leq(\frac{\ln(c)}{\ln(bc)})^2$

Tags: inequality

Let $n$ be a natural number bigger than 2 and $b \in [\frac{1}{n},1]$ and $c \in [n+\frac{1}{n},n+1]$. Prove that for any positive real number $x$

$b^x\leq(\frac{\ln(c)}{\ln(bc)})^2$.

First I wrote $\ln(bc) = \ln(b)+\ln(c)$ and I tried doing some comparisons and I tried differentiating but I think the function is decreasing. I'm not fully sure the inequality is true so if it isn't please provide a counterexample.

I think I found a solution but I'm not sure it's right. Because $b \leq 1$, $b^x \leq 1$. And $\frac{\ln(c)}{\ln(b)+\ln(c)} \geq 1$ because $\ln(c) \geq \ln(2+\frac{1}{2}) > 0$ and $\ln(b) \leq \ln(1) = 0$. Equality is achieved when $b=1$.

Comment: Maybe turn your add-/edition into an answer.

Comment: Not sure what you deem a proof, but as you say clearly the LHS is $\leq 1$ for the given values of $b$ and $x$ while the RHS is clearly $\geq 1$.

Answer (score 1):

$x>0$ so $b \leq 1$ implies $\ln(b)\leq 0$ and $b^x \leq 1$. But $(\frac{\ln(c)}{\ln(bc)})^2 = (\frac{\ln(c)}{\ln(b)+\ln(c)})^2$ and because $c \geq 2$, implying $\ln(c)>0$, $(\frac{\ln(c)}{\ln(b)+\ln(c)})^2 \geq 1 \geq b^x$. Equality is reached when $b=1$.